# Get active subscriptions In-app Billing Android

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing, in-app-subscription, play-billing-library

I have used the In-app billing library for adding subscriptions in my app. Everything is working properly but I am unable to find how do I get a Users current active subscription?

As per the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient#queryPurchaseHistoryAsync%28java.lang.String,%20com.android.billingclient.api.PurchaseHistoryResponseListener%29), the method `queryPurchaseHistoryAsync` returns the most recent purchase made by the user for each SKU, even if that purchase is expired, canceled, or consumed. Due to this, I am unable to know whether a current subscription is active or not.

According to [this](https://medium.com/bleeding-edge/testing-in-app-purchases-on-android-a6de74f78878) post, if we cancel the subscription, it will still be considered active for that day. But I am getting the subscriptions in the response which were canceled before 15 days.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most of the applications stores the subscription transaction in their own DB as well, do you maintain any database in your application ?

Comment: I have not yet implemented subscriptions, but I am quite sure that queryPurchases() returns the currently valid purchases. Do you have problems with that query?

Comment: Who got the bounty?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To query users subscription i use this method:

```
public void querySubscriptions() {
    Runnable queryToExecute = () -> {
        Purchase.PurchasesResult purchasesResult = mBillingClient.queryPurchases(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS);

        if (mBillingClient == null ||
                purchasesResult.getResponseCode() != BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK) {
            return;
        }
        mPurchases.clear();
        onPurchasesUpdated(BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK, purchasesResult.getPurchasesList());
    };

    executeServiceRequest(queryToExecute);
}
```

If you need more details, ask.

Comment: Does this method return only active subscriptions or does it also return previously purchased subscription?

Comment: It will return only active subscriptions. You can test it, here is a link on how to test subscriptions: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing#testing-subscriptions

Comment: how to use this to trigger something?

Answer (score -1):

A user can have multiple subscriptions active at any moment. You can check whether the subscription is active or not using `isAutoRenewing` method.Here is the docs for that method

> Indicates whether the subscription renews automatically. If true, the subscription is active, and will automatically renew on the next billing date. If false, indicates that the user has canceled the subscription. The user has access to subscription content until the next billing date and will lose access at that time unless they re-enable automatic renewal (or manually renew, as described in Manual Renewal). If you offer a grace period, this value remains set to true for all subscriptions, as long as the grace period has not lapsed. The next billing date is extended dynamically every day until the end of the grace period or until the user fixes their payment method.

Comment: How do I identify the case where the auto-renewal is set to false but still 10 days are left for the subscription? How can I allow user to access premium features until the subscription is expired?

Comment: Dude, this is not correct. Read the text from the doc you posted.